# XCode 6.3 Init() No Longer Compiles

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Just upgraded to XCode 6.3 and have gotten all of the compile errors ironed out except for one that appears on numerous classes of mine.

I do the following in an example class:

```
init()
{
    super.init()

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!
}
```

This returns the following error on the super.init() call:

```
Must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'UITableViewController'
```

Anybody seen this or come up with a fix yet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must use the designated initializer of `UITableViewController`, that is

```
init(style style: UITableViewStyle)
```

for example:

```
super.init(style: .Plain)
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks! Will mark as answer whenever it allows me to.

Comment: Note that if any designated initializers exist at all, `init()` will generate a compiler error. `init()` is only available in the absense of any other init methods that accept parameters. This is why `init()` may be acceptable in some cases but unacceptable in others.

Comment: Also looking at the API Diffs especially between 8.2 and 8.3 a lot more designated initializers are being added to existing classes as they seem to be made more swift compliant.